# how to make checkbox visible on multiple selects

Tags: android

"I have a common controller. In that there are 2 fields. Text field and a checkbox." My question is that "when user selects single item,the check box should not be visible and when the user selects multiple items, the check box should be visible." This is in android. Please guide me through this.

the code is as given below:

public class ProfileItemDialogFilterableAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

```
List<SelectableItem> mItemList;
private LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;
public static int mSingleSelection = 1;
public static int mMultipleSelection = 2;
private int mSelectedPosition;
private int mSelectionMode;
private Context mContext;

public ProfileItemDialogFilterableAdapter(Context context, List<SelectableItem> itemList) {
    mItemList = itemList;
    mLayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    mContext = context;

}

@Override
public ProfileItemDialogFilterableAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemLayoutView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_profile_item_dialog, parent, false);

    return new ViewHolder(itemLayoutView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ProfileItemDialogFilterableAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    SelectableItem current = mItemList.get(position);

    if (current == null)
        return;

    holder.mLabelName.setText(current.getName());

    if (mSelectionMode == mMultipleSelection){

        holder.mCheckBoxItem.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.mCheckBoxItem.setChecked(current.isSelected());
    }
    else {
        holder.mCheckBoxItem.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        if (position == mSelectedPosition) {
            holder.mLabelName.setTextColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorBackground));
            holder.mLabelName.setBackgroundColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));

        } else {
            holder.mLabelName.setTextColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.textColorFullBlack));
            holder.mLabelName.setBackgroundColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorBackground));
        }
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return (mItemList != null ? mItemList.size() : 0);
}

public void setResult(List<SelectableItem> itemList) {
    mItemList = itemList;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    CheckBox mCheckBoxItem;
    TextView mLabelName;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        mCheckBoxItem = (CheckBox) itemView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox_item);
        mLabelName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.label_name);
        mCheckBoxItem.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onCheckedChangeListener);
        mLabelName.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
    }

    CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener onCheckedChangeListener = new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

            mItemList.get(getAdapterPosition()).setSelected(isChecked);

        }
    };

    View.OnClickListener onClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            mSelectedPosition = getAdapterPosition();
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };
}
```

}

Comment: search on google .What you tried so far ?

Comment: post your code here

Comment: where does the user select single or multiple item?

Comment: actually it is a pop up window. For example "if a user wants to select the country. he will select single country. so that time checkbox should not be visible. the same control is used at different place with different values. that time user can select multiple options. that time the checkbox should be visible.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `listener` to your selection (single or multiple) and inside the `listener` change the visibility of the `checkbox`.

Comment: Can you add your current Code for selecting Single or multiple